# How to run Dockerfile or Dock Image to install the python dependencies

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Sorry for basic Question, as I am new on Docker and I want to install the dependencies by using the docker file, So please guide me how to run this file on Ubuntu?

Author have written the dependencies in the Dockerfile for building the Opensfm.

GitHub Repository [Link](https://github.com/paulinus/opensfm-docker-base/blob/master/Dockerfile.python3)

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04

    # Install apt-getable dependencies
    RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
```

Can anyone guide me how to run the file and install the dependencies on Ubuntu?

Comment: Please go through this https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should follow mchawre's advice and read the docker get-started. However, I can try to direct you into the right direction.

> I want to install the dependencies by using the docker file

You have to understand that a docker file compiles to a docker image which then can be run as a docker container. You can think of a docker container as a lightweight virtual machine. With this in mind, your statement does not make sense, since you can not install dependencies for your host system (the system in which you might want to start the docker container) with the help of a docker image. This is not how docker containers are supposed to work.

Instead, the docker file allows you to create a virtualized (isolated) environment in which you can ssh (the docker way: `docker exec -it <container_name> bash`) and then build the respective application.

If you do not want to mess with docker at all and your systems runs something close to ubuntu:18.04, you can also manually execute the instruction from the docker file on your normal system in order to build your desired application on your system.